# send emails based on dataset column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way to send emails from a Power BI report based on the email addresses generated in a column of that report?

I am new to PowerBI and would need any leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to send e-mails from Power BI report. You must write code to perform such task.